# Meaning of the idiomatic "biscuits and gravy"

Tags: word-meaning, idioms, expressions

In the movie *Line of Duty* (about 45:30 in), a guy huge gets a weight thrown at him in a gym. Surprisingly not very bothered nor hurt, he says:

> "Biscuits and gravy, bitch!"

and then starts to fight the entered policeman.

What's the meaning and etymology of the expression? I've googled for it but got only a bunch of recipes...

Comment: Possibly an American version of *[This is all] **meat and drink** [to me]* or *[This is my] **bread and butter*** - implying that the speaker has easily dealt with the threat (by implication, saying he could ***eat the assailant for breakfast***). Or perhaps ***Here's something I can really get my teeth into!*** It doesn't make much difference exactly how you "deconstruct" it - the guy's obviously ***relishing*** the upcoming fight, and it's a "feeding / appetite-based" metaphoric usage.

Comment: Is this the only time this line is used in the film? What other things does this character say? *Biscuits and gravy* isn't an idiomatic expression for anything other than the particular dish, so there could be any number of interpretations here.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Duh? I asked politely about a subject I haven't heard of. It's not a vastly known issue and I don't really care for the tone of your response. I showed interest in a matter that might be a good cause and the way I was replied to didn't really wake my empathy for said cause. Thank you for the suggested answer. Other than that, I wish not to communicate with you on any subject whatsoever. Thank you in advance for respecting my wish.

Comment: @choster It's a bi-role and he's not doing much else, regrettably. I didn't recognize the idiom neither but supporting humble approach, I wished to verify with the community in that regard.

Comment: *Biscuits and gravy* is a Southern U.S. breakfast food named for its ingredients. In North American usage (but [not elsewhere](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/41638)), a *biscuit* is a round bun of soft, crumbly, unsweetened quickbread. The gravy, traditionally a white gravy made from pork sausage and milk, is poured on top. It is a very simple, very easily cooked, and very filling dish to make. Used metaphorically, it could be interpreted a dozen different ways. Without a clip, I won't venture to guess if any of them were intended or not.

Comment: @choster I can provide the missing info in text, as there's no clip to show due to copyright reasons. It **might** be interpreted as the big guy doesn't even feel the pain expected to be caused by the hit of the weight. He also looks at the upcoming fight with the police officer not so much as a frightening challenge but rather as a fun and enjoyable quick meal. C.f. *I'll eat him for breakfast*, which sounds as the most appropriate interpretation given the optics.